# Analogous network protocol for transmitting messages using istream/ostream

Tags: c++, stl, iostream, ifstream, istringstream

This was a question from a coding challenge and I couldn't figure out the way to do it -

Implement encode() and decode() for a simple wire protocol per the prototypes below:

```
void encode ( const std::string& inputFilename, std::ostream& out );
void decode ( std::istream& in, const std:string& outputFilename );
```

Lets say there are several files and each contains a single message. As it already says from the prototype, encode must read single specified file from disk and place message in the ostream.

Decode must read single encoded message from istream and place it in the specified file. The contents of the two corresponding files must be identical.

It is easy if I could read the file in the encode method and place the data in a buffer and send them to another file in the decode method, but that is not the question. How do I read data from `std::istream` without someone actually typing the data on the console (like `std::cin`)?

Thank you in advance for your time and would love to see responses for this!

Answer (score 1):

istream is a parent class for ifstream (input file stream) and istringstream (input string stream), so you can pass as a input parameter ifstream or istringstream. Do not need to use cin.
The same applies to out parameter, you can provide object of the ofstream or ostringstream. This is well know mechanism in C++ to abstract what particular type of stream you deal with.

Comment: Thank you for the pointing me at the right direction. As I started exploring more on I/OStringstream, I have learned that I will have to use ostringstream::rdbuf to copy the data in the stream from encode to decode. Is that the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a piece of code that works with the prototypes given in the question. I am sure there could be more ways of doing it but I thought I would share this.

```
class fileIO
{
private:
    std::string inBuf;
public:
    std::stringstream testbuf; 
    void encode(const std::string& inputFilename, std::ostream& out);
    void decode ( std::istream& in, const std::string& outputFilename);
};

void fileIO::encode(const std::string& inputFilename, std::ostream& out)
{
    //read from the input file and stream it to ostream
    ifstream infile(inputFilename);
    while(infile.good()){
        getline(infile, inBuf);
        out << inBuf;
    }
    cout << "Value stored in outBuf: " << inBuf << endl;
    infile.close();
}

void fileIO::decode(std::istream& in, const std::string& outputFilename)
{
    //read from istream and output it to a file
    string val;
    ofstream ofile(outputFilename);
    in >> val;
    cout<< "Read the istream contents: " << val << endl;
    ofile << val;

    ofile.close();
}
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    fileIO File; 
    string inputFile;
    cout << "Enter input File Name: "<< endl;
    cin >> inputFile;

    File.encode(inputFile, File.testbuf);
    File.decode(File.testbuf, inputFile);
    return 0;
}
```

I am passing "a stringstream" to both encode and decode since istream and ostream are the parent class of stringstream. In this solution, the value from the input file is stored in the stringstream and gets passed on to decode where the value from the same stringstream gets written to output file.